# Create multiple, but submit only one form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to submit a formular via jQuery - if it's only one form - it works nice, but if there are more than form, it doesn't work (result is page reload).

I want to create for every user a jQuery Accordion segment - where I am able to edit the user. - no problem
But the forms in the segment have all the same IDs.

In the jQuery-Part i have to enter the ID of the form - my problem is, that I dont know how to do this with a prefix or something.

Here is the Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#useredit').bind('submit', function() {
            var form = $('#useredit');
            var data = form.serialize();
            $.post('entry.php', data, function(response) {
                document.getElementById("usereditp").innerHTML = response;       
            });
            return false;           
        });             
    });
</script>

<?php
try { 
    echo'<div id="accordion">';
    foreach ($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `user` order by nachname;') as $useredit) {
        echo'<h3>'.$useredit['nachname'].', '.$useredit['vorname'].'</h3>
        <div>
        <p>
        <form id="useredit" action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="formular" value="useredit">
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'.$useredit['id'].'" />
        <input type="text" name="benutzer" value="'.$useredit['username'].'" /><br />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Passwort" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="vorname" value="'.$useredit['vorname'].'" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="nachname" value="'.$useredit['nachname'].'" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="tel" value="'.@$useredit['tel'].'" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="write"';
            if($useredit['schreiben'] == 1){
                echo "checked";
            }
        echo' /> Schreibrechte &laquo;&raquo; 
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" id="delete"> mit allen Schichten löschen 
        <input type="submit" value="Speichern" />
        </form>
        </p>
        </div>';
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    echo "Datenbankfehler: Die Daten konnten nicht gelesen werden.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class (which can be used for multiple elements) to each form and bind that to the submit action. Then, set each form to have a unique ID and select it in the jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.usereditform').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $(this);
        var data = form.serialize();
        $.post('entry.php', data, function(response) {
            document.getElementById("usereditp").innerHTML = response;       
        });
        return false;           
    });             
});
</script>

<?php
try { 


echo'<div id="accordion">';
foreach ($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `user` order by nachname;') as $useredit) {
    echo'<h3>'.$useredit['nachname'].', '.$useredit['vorname'].'</h3>
    <div>
    <p>
    <form id="useredit_'.$useredit['id'].'" class="usereditform" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formular" value="useredit">
```

Comment: Great, that works!
But the form tag should look like this:
`<form id="useredit_'.$useredit['id'].'" class="usereditform" action="" method="post">`
Thank you!

Comment: never used PHP so not really familiar with the syntax